# <> and != avoiding NULL in WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table `PATIENT` with Column `STATUS`. When I queried to get `STATUS` not equal to 1, I was expecting the result as `NULL` and 2.

But I am only getting 2 as the result. Can someone help me with this?

```
CREATE TABLE #PATIENT
(STATUS INT)

INSERT INTO #PATIENT (STATUS)
SELECT 1 
UNION
SELECT 2 
UNION 
SELECT NULL 

SELECT * FROM #PATIENT WHERE STATUS <> 1
```

When I queried with

```
SELECT * FROM #PATIENT  WHERE ISNULL(STATUS, 0) != 1
```

I am able to get `NULL` and 2 as the result.

This is SQL SERVER 2012.

Comment: A NULL value compared to anything is false. This is not the same as saying that NULL is not equal to anything; it's not unequal either :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OR` in `WHERE` with Condition `STATUS IS NULL` .

```
 SELECT * FROM #PATIENT WHERE STATUS <> 1 OR STATUS IS NULL
```

This will do it.

**EDIT**:

> Conceptually, `NULL` means `“a missing unknown value”` and it is
>   treated somewhat differently from other values.
>
> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as `=, <, or <>`
>   to test for `NULL`
>
> Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with `NULL is also`
>   `NULL`, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons

we can not equate or not equate anything with `null`, thats why `IS NULL`

> `SELECT NULL <> 1`  ===> `NULL`
>
> ```
>  Even though it is supposed to be true, it will return `NULL`
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I am unable to understand why it is avoiding NULL when I queried with <> 1

Comment: @umesh because NULL is non-existant

Comment: Thanks @SubinCPoonamgode

Answer (score 1):

When you compare NULL value to any value then the result is always NULL.

So if you wan to select the NULL value as well then try this:

```
SELECT * FROM #PATIENT WHERE STATUS <> 1 OR STATUS IS NULL
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/797e6/1)**

Comment: re: *the result is always 0*: the result is always **NULL**, which is not `true` and therefore has behaviour as if it's `false`. Query is good though.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually "NULL" means a missing value. To test for NULL IS NULL or IS NOT NULL condition is used. Arithmetic operators cannot be used for comparing NULL values.

NULL<>1 :: returns false because NULL can be 1 or any other value (an unknown value).

Answer (score 0):

Null is a special marker used in Structured Query Language (SQL) to indicate that a data value does not exist in the database.
And reason because you got only 2 and NOT NULL is because in SQL nothing is equal to NULL but also nothing is **NOT** equal to NULL.
In Simple words you cannot equate and not equate any value with NULL.